# Create and Write to a text file using an excel macro and VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a macro and VBA code to create a text file with a specific format. All the data needed to create the text file is gathered from the macro cells.
I have attached pictures of the macro data file and the output text file (please see below).

[excel macro with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay25l.png)

[Desired output txt format-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znt2t.png)

Also, below is my VBA code I generated to get data from the macro and create/write into a text file. I still need to figure out how to write it in the specified format (Desired output txt format-example).

```
 Sub ExcelToTxt() 
'Declaring variables 
Dim lCounter As Long 
Dim lLastRow As Long 
Dim destgroup As String 
Dim parmlabel as Variant 
Dim FName As Variant 

'Activate Sheet1 
Sheet1.Activate 

'Find the last row that contains data 
With Sheet1 
    lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlDown).Row 
End With

'Create txt file 
FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", "txt file (*.txt), *.txt") 

'Open FName For Output As #1
For lCounter = 2 To lLastRow 
    'Read specific data from the worksheet 
    With Sheet1 destgroup = .Cells(lCounter, 19) 
        parmlabel = .Cells(lCounter, 8) 
        If destgroup="trex_15hz" Or destgroup="trex_10hz" Or destgroup="trex_5hz" Then 
            'Write selected data to text file 
            'Write #1, parmlabel 
        End If
    End With
'Continue looping until the last row 
Next lCounter 

'Close the text file 
Close #1 

End Sub
```

Any help with what I need to add in my VBA to create the formatted output txt file will be greatly appreciate it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there. People won't go to another site to see what you have.

Comment: Thank you for the edit @BerticusMaximus!  I appreciate it.

Comment: Create a "template" for the LABEL DEFINITION block, where the variable parts are represented by tokens such as "<LSB>", "<MSB>" etc.  Use `Replace()` to replace each token with the value from the worksheet line you're exporting.  When done replacing, write out that block to your text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the data into an array and then convert it back into text.

```
Sub ExcelToTxt()
'Declaring variables
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer
    Dim n As Long, k As Long
    Dim destgroup As String
    Dim FName As String
    Dim vDB, vR(1 To 6), vJoin(), vResult()
    Dim sJoin As String, sResult As String
    Dim s As Long
    'Activate Sheet1
    Sheet1.Activate

    'Find the last row that contains data
    With Sheet1
        vDB = .Range("a1").CurrentRegion '<~~ get data to array from your data range
        n = UBound(vDB, 1) 'size of array (row of 2 dimension array)
    End With

    'Create txt file
    FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", "txt file (*.txt), *.txt")

    For i = 2 To n '<~~loop
            destgroup = vDB(i, 2) '<~~ second column
            If destgroup = "trex_15hz" Or destgroup = "trex_10hz" Or destgroup = "trex_5hz" Then

                vR(1) = "; ### LABEL DEFINITION ###" '<~~ text 1st line
                s = Val(Replace(vDB(i, 3), "label", ""))
                vR(2) = "EQ_LABEL_DEF,02," & Format(s, "000")
                vR(3) = "UDB_LABEL," & Chr(34) & vDB(i, 4) & Chr(34) '<~~ 2nd line

                    ReDim vJoin(4 To 7)
                    vJoin(4) = Chr(34) & vDB(i, 4) & Chr(34)
                    For j = 5 To 7
                        vJoin(j) = vDB(i, j)
                    Next j
                    sJoin = Join(vJoin, ",")

                vR(4) = "STD_SUB_LABE," & sJoin '<~~ 3th line

                    ReDim vJoin(8 To 12)
                    vJoin(8) = Chr(34) & UCase(vDB(i, 8)) & Chr(34)
                    vJoin(9) = Chr(34) & vDB(i, 9) & Chr(34)
                    vJoin(10) = Format(vDB(i, 10), "#.000000000")
                    For j = 11 To 12
                        vJoin(j) = vDB(i, j)
                    Next j
                    sJoin = Join(vJoin, ",")

                vR(5) = "STD_SUB_LABE," & sJoin '<~~ 4the line
                vR(6) = "END_EQ_LABEL_DEF"  '<~~ 5th line
                k = k + 1
                ReDim Preserve vResult(1 To k)
                vResult(k) = Join(vR, vbCrLf) '<~~ 5 line in array vR and get to array vResult with join method
            End If
    Next i
    sResult = "EQUIPMENT_ID_DEF,02,0x1," & Chr(34) & "trex" & Chr(34) '<~~ text file first line
    sResult = sResult & vbCrLf & Join(vResult, vbCrLf) '<~~ combine 1th and other line

    ConvertText FName, sResult '<~~ sub presedure
End Sub
Sub ConvertText(myfile As String, strTxt As String)
    Dim objStream

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With objStream
        '.Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .WriteText strTxt
        .SaveToFile myfile, 2
        .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, you are awesome!  One more thing, can you please explain a little bit in more detail the lines of code you included? I would appreciate it.  Thank you!

Comment: vDB is static array, vR()  is dynamice array.   vJion() is dynamic array

Comment: I think you are missing one row in the output file : EQ_LABEL_DEF,02, <source parameter name>       How would you integrate that row if the source parameter name is a string in the data but I want only the integer in the output?   Thank you

Comment: @Jesus, you are right. I missed. What mean 02  and 001?

Comment: 001 it's the number from column 3 (source parameter name). I just want to extract the number, not the string (label1 ----> 001)

Comment: 02 is just static, that number doesn't change. The only number that changes is the 001, 002, 003....

Comment: @jesus,  you mean extracting from string "label1" to 001?

Comment: Great, that worked! Thank you a lot man.  One more question... can you please explain what the lines below mean and also why are you using sub ConverText function at the end. Thank you, that should be everything :)                                                                                     
                 k = k + 1
                ReDim Preserve vResult(1 To k)
                vResult(k) = Join(vR, vbCrLf) '<~~ 5 line in array vR and get to array vResult with join method

Comment: @Jesus,  the vR  get data( 6 lines in your text) from your sheet one line. Later put this 6 lines  in a array vResult(i). Finally vResult holds the contents of the entire line.  vCrLf is new line mark.   This array change to String sRelsut  by jion()  method.

Comment: sub ConverText function ~~>  it use adodb.stream. it change  string to text file.

Comment: Thank you! I am done with my coding and it works awesome! Thanks for all your help :)